# Open subset of the commuting variety

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $C_n$ be the variety of pairs of commuting $n\times n$ matrices (let's say over $\mathbb C$).
It is known to be irreducible and it is conjecturally normal.
Let $f:C_n\to \mathfrak{gl}(n)$ be the map sending $(X,Y)$ to $XY$. Let $C_n^0=f^{-1}(\mathfrak{gl}(n)_{reg})$ where by $\mathfrak{gl}(n)_{reg}$ I mean the open subset of regular matrices (i.e. those, whose centralizer has dimension $n$).

$\mathbf{Question:}$ Is $C_n^0$ affine? Equivalently, is the complement of $C_n^0$ a Cartier divisor in $C_n$? If yes, what are the components of this divisor?

Comment: It's not known to be normal? That's surprising.